# Running flask cli commands on Heroku

Tags: heroku, flask, heroku-postgres

In Flask we can define [CLI](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/dev/cli/) commands by passing it to `app.cli.command`

It's all fine and dandy, and I can run my `initdb` command on my local machine with `python3 -m flask -a appname initdb`

I've uploaded the app successfully to Heroku, and it's live and working except for the pages that require database interaction. My initdb command itself should already work with Heroku, with *one* problem, I cannot run `initdb` on Heroku.

Running this `heroku run python3 -m flask -a appname initdb` produces the output:

> Usage: python -m flask [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...
>
> Error: No such command "initdb".

While using `heroku run python3 -m flask -a appname.py initdb` produces the following: (the same command without heroku run also initializes the db on my machine:

> ▸    Couldn't find that app.

Which is weird since running `heroku ls` allows me to see `appname.py` on the current directory.

Comment: If your app follows the [cookiecutter-flask](https://github.com/sloria/cookiecutter-flask/blob/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.app_name%7D%7D/README.rst) conventions, you'll need to [set your environment variables](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars): `heroku config:set FLASK_APP=/path/to/autoapp.py`

Comment: To anyone else who got this problem: If you are installing your app in heroku (e.g. if you have a setup.py), you can just run `heroku config:set FLASK_APP=name_of_your_flask_app` and skip the correct-path hassle.

Answer (score 1):

If you encouter this error:

> Couldn't find that app.

It is because you passed an invalid app name as your `-a, --app` option for `heroku run`. Run `heroku apps` to find what are valid names and try again.